# How to iterate through array and change some values to floats?

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to iterate through this array and change all the numbers from strings to floats.

[image]

I don't want to do anything with the Letters or Words, those can stay strings.

I need the array to update with the changes so that I can use indexes to access the numbers & use them for subtraction later down the road.

Can you please help me? Maybe with a try except?

Comment: test the type of being string and containing a number you can test with a regex `\d+\.\d+` and then convert, you can use a double `map`

Comment: You should paste the data as text in case someone wants to test it. Also, what datatype is it? I would expect there to be commas if it was a list.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an example with a list.
Use a regex is surely a more elegant solution, anyway this should work

Python code:

```
data = ['A', '2.4', '3.8', None, 0.18]
data_new = []

for item in data:
  if item != None and (isinstance(item, int) or isinstance(item, float) or item.replace('.', '', 1).isdigit()):
    item = float(item)
  data_new.append(item)

for item in data_new:
  print(item)
```

Output:

```
A
2.4
3.8
None
0.18
```

It casts every item in the list to float if they aren't none or numbers (also float) as string.